# History of Kabbalah

Tags: history, mysticism-kabbalah, mesorah-tradition

Has anyone attempted to write a historical sketch of the history of the *shalsheles HaKabbalah* (which, in this instance, I use to refer to Toras HaSod)? In other words, what was *megale* to Moshe Rabbenu, what Rav Shimon Bar Yochai did to (skipping many many generations, I know) what the Ramak did to what the Arizal did etc.

Looking for a non-academic work, if it exists.

Comment: This is audio and probably not exactly what your looking for but it’s good stuff https://insidechassidus.org/thought-and-history/123-kabbala-and-philosophy-series/1537-a-brief-history-of-kabbalah and https://insidechassidus.org/thought-and-history/123-kabbala-and-philosophy-series/554-the-kabbala-series-classes-1-20

Answer (score 1):

The following link is a rough translation into English of an introduction that appeared in a reprint of Sefer Shomer Emunim in 1965. It was originally written by Rabbi Yitzchok Stern of Givat Shaul in Israel.

It was intended to be read together with [Sefer Shomer Emunim](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=39500&st=&pgnum=1) which is considered an introduction to learning the Sod aspect of the Torah.

It gives a historical sketch from the time of Moshe Rabbeinu up until the time of the Ba'al Shem Tov and the early generations of the Chassidic movement.

[Introduction to Sefer Shomer Emunim](http://www.torahlab.org/download/shomer_emunim.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

In Rav Elya Weintraub's *sefer Nefesh Eliyahu- Hakdamos V'Shiurim*, he has an essay where he dedicates part of the essay to explaining the development of Kabbalah from Rav Shimon Bar Yochai to the Vilna Gaon.